# How can I test that a composable is not displayed, but also accept if it doesn't exist?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

In my test of my Compose UI, I'd like to test that nothing matching my `matcher` is displayed. I found two ways to check that:

1. `onNode(matcher).assertDoesNotExist()`
2. `onNode(matcher).assertIsNotDisplayed()`

Unfortunately, in my experience so far, certain Composables after being removed respond in my tests to "does not exist" and others (particularly `LazyList` items) respond to "is not displayed". If it's not displayed but still exists, `assertDoesNotExist()` will fail. And if it doesn't exist, `assertIsNotDisplayed()` will fail. (!)

As one would expect, I don't care whether Compose thinks something technically "exists" or not, I just want to test if it's gone from the user's point of view. So how can I assert that either one of these would pass?

Since these are assertions, and not boolean functions, I can't use `or`.

If I call both of the assertions, it's guaranteed that one of them will fail.

And I haven't been able to find any matcher with semantics like "is displayed". If one did exist, I could do

```
onNode(matcher and isDisplayed()).assertDoesNotExist()
```

But there's no `isDisplayed` matcher that I can find.

It's easy to test the opposite, that something exists *and* is displayed: `assertIsDisplayed()` does that. How can I test the opposite of `assertIsDisplayed()`, that it *either* doesn't exist *or* is not displayed?

Comment: I find it ironic that I'm failing to write my tests of a "Compose" UI because the Compose testing library is giving me assertions but no boolean tests, and assertions don't *compose* as well as boolean tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue on the Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187188981) that describes your problem.

The Jetpack Compose team [updated](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2787059)  the testing methods in Compose UI [`1.6.0-beta01`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.6.0-beta01):

> The children of SubcomposeLayout (and layouts like LazyColumn based on it) which are retained to be reused in future are considered deactivated. New assertIsDeactivated() test API was introduced to test such nodes. **The rests of the test apis will filter out deactivated nodes by default.** (I2ef84, b/187188981)

To get the updated behavior for `assertDoesNotExist()` and `assertIsNotDisplayed()`, use the following dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.1"
```

The reason why you needed to use `assertIsNotDisplayed()` previously is that `LazyColumn` or `LazyRow` recycle the item layouts. So even when an item was removed from a list, the layout of the item still existed because it was recycled for another item. As these recycle nodes will be filtered out now by the testing methods, the test methods should behave as expected.
 If you want to test whether an item layout was kept for recycling, you can use the newly introduced `assertIsDeactivated()` assertion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try that soon. Just recently a new BOM was added for 1.6.1.

Comment: Also, I'm feeling silly to never have thought of their solution to catch the assertion exception and reverse it. Though I'm equally amazed that, after seeing problems like this, they would still not expose a boolean-returning function in the public API.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but for me this does not feel like a proper solution :D

Comment: OK, so like you suspected, they fixed both `assertDoesNotExist()` and `assertIsNotDisplayed()`, now I can use either. (Or more correctly, choose to use "displayed" if I want it to not count things scrolled off screen, and "exists" otherwise.) `assertIsDeactivated()`, though, tests specifically for the situation that used to cause a problem, pre-1.6 (so will fail the assertion for most composables in most situations). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for testing! Then I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the source code for `assertIsDisplayed`, I see that it gets the `SemanticsNode` and then checks a bunch of conditions, one of them being that the layout is "placed". I wrote my own check for that, and found that the compose items I was looking to test are indeed "not placed" when they exist but are gone from the screen:

```
fun SemanticsNode.isPlaced(): Boolean {
    var layoutInfo: LayoutInfo? = this.layoutInfo
    while (layoutInfo != null) {
        if (!layoutInfo.isPlaced) return false
        layoutInfo = layoutInfo.parentInfo
    }
    return true
}

fun assertGone(matcher: SemanticsMatcher, useUnmergedTree: Boolean = false) {
    for (node in composeRule.onAllNodes(matcher, useUnmergedTree).fetchSemanticsNodes()) {
        assertTrue("A node matching [${matcher.description}] isn't gone", !node.isPlaced())
    }
}
```